# Why aren't my checkboxes registering as checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I've been struggling with a CheckBox column in a GridView in ASP .NET / C#. When finished, this page should display current open positions for my office. People should be able to check as many positions as they'd like to apply for and then continue to the next screen (where the actual application begins).

This is the routine I run when the 'Apply Now' button is clicked. I found this code on here after trying about a dozen other combinations suggested by my boss and people on here. When I run it, isChecked = false, so it doesn't run anything within that if statement. Am I missing something obvious?

```
for (int i = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
    bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbx_apply")).Checked;

    if (isChecked)
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Write("Hello world");
            PositionsAppliedFor.Add(Convert.ToInt32((GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text)));
            Session["SelectedPositionIDList"] = PositionsAppliedFor;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Response.Write(error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also, I realize the stuff I'm doing within the if statement isn't anything important.. I'm just trying to get it to do /something/.

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
              onselectedindexchanged="UpdateSelectedPostions">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbx_apply" runat="server" 
                              OnCheckedChanged="UpdateSelectedPostions"
                              AutoPostBack="false"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Simple, and probably missing a lot. I'm /very/ new to ASP.NET.

This is where I load the data for the grid and bind it:

```
string sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM dbo.POSITION WHERE PositionStartDate < GETDATE() AND PositionEndDate > GETDATE()";
command = new SqlCommand(sqlstatement, connection);
ds = new DataSet();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
connection.Close();
```

Hopefully this is enough, because it's really all I have. I haven't put anything else on the page yet - just trying to get these stupid checkboxes to agree with me.

Comment: You'll need to add you aspx code too.

Comment: We'll need more information. Where is this code executed? I assume it is inside a handler, but a handler for which event?

Comment: Hi Ellie, are you binding this gridview in the page load event?

Comment: Oh, sure. Let me add that code. Hold on.

Comment: And the first bit of code is within a button_click routine.

Comment: I made it its own routine, but it's called in the Page_Load method.

Comment: Are you rebinding on every page load?

Comment: Are you checking for !Page.IsPostBack ? @geek I'm thinking the same thing too.

Comment: @geekchic: Yes I am. Should I not?

Comment: It's rebinding and resetting your choices every postback

Comment: @HerNameIsEllie You'll be undoing the checking.

Comment: @jadarnel27: It gets called in the Page_Load method.

Comment: @geekchic: Okay, that makes sense, but how do I only bind the data once?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for all the duplicate requests for information =)  I deleted my comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your binding code is in a block like this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{

}
```

Otherwise you'll be recreating the checkboxes on each postback and therefore losing the fact that they're checked.

Comment: WORKED PERFECTLY! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

If your code

```
string sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM dbo.POSITION WHERE PositionStartDate < GETDATE() AND PositionEndDate > GETDATE()";
command = new SqlCommand(sqlstatement, connection);
ds = new DataSet();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
connection.Close();
```

Is in the page_load method this will be called every time you post back, you should read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) which will give you a better understanding about this.

To avoid it running this code every time you postback wrap your code with this

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{

}
```

Also on a side note, you are calling the UpdateSelectedPostions on both CheckChanged and SelectedIndexChanged are you meaning to do this?

Comment: Thanks! I only accepted geekchic's over yours because she answered first.

Comment: What does UpdateSelectedPostions do is that the C# code you posted